# Inequality $\lambda_1 \|x\|^2\leq\langle Tx,x \rangle\leq \lambda_n \|x\|^2$ for non symmetric matrices $T$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We know that, if a $n\times n$ real matrix $T$ is symmetric positive definite, it has real eigenvalues $0\leq\lambda_1\leq\dots\leq \lambda_n$ and:
$$\lambda_1 \|x\|^2\leq\langle Tx,x \rangle\leq \lambda_n \|x\|^2\, . \quad \quad (*)$$
What happens if the $n\times n$ matrix $T$ has real eigenvalues $0\leq\lambda_1\leq\dots\leq \lambda_n$ but it is not symmetric? In particular, does inequality (*) still applies? I think that it may no longer be true, because $T$ is no longer symmetric and may not be diagonalizable. Then, I wonder if inequality (*) still applies in the case of real eigenvalues $0\leq\lambda_1\leq\dots\leq \lambda_n$ and $T$ diagonalizable. For the latter question I have no idea what to say.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the case where it is diagonalizable with non negative eigenvalues, this need not hold for the Euclidean norm and inner product but it does hold in the inner product under which $T $ is self-adjoint. It also holds either way if you replace the eigenvalues by singular values.